# How can I create my own dynamic object similar to ViewBag in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

It is possible to add properties to ViewBag objects dynamically with `.PropertyName` or `["PropertyName"]` that acts like a dictionary. Is there a way to create my own object that accepts property name (of my choice) that holds values (of type objects)?

Comment: Your question is unclear, I think. In what way would a dictionary not suffice?

Comment: Dictionary, as you suggest would be a viable option for the requirement. Just wanted to know if it was possible. If yes, how can one achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
dynamic MyVar = new ExpandoObject() as dynamic;
```

or

```
var MyVar = new ExpandoObject();
```

`ExpandoObject` is in the `System.Dynamic` namespace.